# Sharing Data Between (IOS Application) and (Unity Application) in IOS platform

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, cross-platform

I am developing two applications 
First app (written in **objective_c** ): exports a 3d model as a text 
Second app:the Unity app written in **C#** :a 3d model viewer, it takes a string or a file path to render the exported 3d model from the first app.

I wonder if there is a practical tested way to share data (text) between the two apps Under the **iOS** platform.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both are diff apps or you integrate Unity and iOS ?

Comment: you can achieve your goal using iCloud Common Container for Multiple Apps. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW26

Comment: @sharadchauhan
Both apps are different (the unity app  is isolated from iOS app)
first app : written in objective_c
second app: (unity app) written in c# , then i export it to iOS

Comment: @Jabson
i want the two apps to share data over the same device

Comment: @QusaiAzzam Tell me if I am right, you export unity project as iOS and then integrate it with your iOS app and result is one single app ?

Comment: yes you can configure common iCloud container for your apps. than you can share data between them.

Comment: @sharadchauhan yes, can is use the same (app_group)  ?
i tried it without beneficial results

Comment: @Jabson how to configure common iCloud in the iOS device and read the path from Unity ?

Comment: I have already provide you apple documentation link where is described how to configure common iCloud container. To send data from ios app to unity you need to write own plugin. https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html

Comment: @sharadchauhan 
Ok, i get the Idea, this is a way to share messages , a small text , the problem is in the big text (10MB) text , also an image 3MB, is there a simpler way ?